# undefined reference to `__dso_handle' error found in compile gcc9.1.0 source code in ubantu16.4

Tags: linux, gcc

../src/c++98/.libs/libc++98convenience.a(mt_allocator.o): In function `get_freelist': /home/ptxc/下载/gcc/gcc-9.1.0/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/../../../../../libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/mt_allocator.cc:64: undefined reference to` __dso_handle'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/c++98/.libs/libc++98convenience.a(mt_allocator.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined hidden symbol `__dso_handle' can not be used when making a shared object
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:697: recipe for target 'libstdc++.la' failed
make[6]: *** [libstdc++.la] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/ptxc/下载/gcc/gcc-9.1.0/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src'
Makefile:730: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[5]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/ptxc/下载/gcc/gcc-9.1.0/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src'
Makefile:562: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/ptxc/下载/gcc/gcc-9.1.0/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3'
Makefile:487: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ptxc/下载/gcc/gcc-9.1.0/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3'
Makefile:19556: recipe for target 'all-stage1-target-libstdc++-v3' failed

Comment: Hi
Your question is not compressible in that state. Please read [ask]

Comment: I try to compile gcc 9.1.0 to ubuntu 16.4. original gcc is 5.5, I degrade it to gcc 4.6, it still doesn't work. using the follow commands:           #./contrib/download_prerequisites                                                               #../configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-9.1.0  --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-threads=posix --disable-checking --disable-multilib                                             #make

Comment: gcc-9.x can be compiled with gcc-7 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing .... .... gcc-9.x build deps, and configuration https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1j7qE9YKTT313B5VBg3kevzCNiykGkonO?usp=sharing → → `export CC=gcc7 CXX=g++7 && ../gcc-9.1.0/configure --prefix=....` ................ Note: You can have as many gcc/g++ as you want, installed at the same time. But never change or remove the system compiler. ! Reinstall `5.5` !

Comment: I try to compile gcc7.4.3, it still have the same error.   .libs/compatibility-c++0x.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/home/ptxc/下载/gcc-7.4.0/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/../../../../libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/compatibility-c++0x.cc:214: undefined reference to `__dso_handle'
/usr/bin/ld: .libs/compatibility-c++0x.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined hidden symbol `__dso_handle' can not be used when making a shared object
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**gcc-9.3.0, Ubuntu 16.04** build example

```
$ sudo apt install g++ autoconf libtool gawk flex bison binutils-dev libelf-dev texinfo zlib1g-dev
$ cd /bin/
$ sudo rm sh
$ sudo ln -s bash sh
```

`$ sudo gdebi Downloads/gcc73-c++_7.3.0-1ubuntu16_amd64.deb` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GhAgfvFR4ks38TSI5ZmnHAh6bE29Zg2J/view?usp=sharing

```
$ cd /home/[name]/
$ tar xvf gcc-9.3.0.tar.xz
$ cd gcc-9.3.0/
$ tar xvf mpfr-4.1.0.tar.xz && mv -v mpfr-4.1.0 mpfr
$ tar xvf gmp-6.2.1.tar.xz && mv -v gmp-6.2.1 gmp
$ tar xvf mpc-1.2.1.tar.gz && mv -v mpc-1.2.1 mpc
$ cd ../
$ mkdir build-gcc930 
$ cd build-gcc930/
$ export CC=gcc7 CXX=g++7 && ../gcc-9.3.0/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc93 --program-suffix=93 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-multilib --disable-libstdcxx-pch --with-system-zlib
$ make                 ### No errors
$ sudo make install
```

Result: `gcc93-c++_9.3.0-16_amd64.deb`  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1io8oWdMupAUK_QXkGB928RmqeSt-5FuQ/view?usp=sharing Provides `/usr/bin/{gcc93, g++93, gfortran93}`